# Redraw GtkWidget

Tags: c, gtk

I have a GtkImage that I am manipulating with a GdkPixbuf. When I change it, I need to redraw it to make the changes take effect. Right now I am doing this by hiding and then showing the image. What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[gtk_widget_queue_draw()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw) function invalidates the widget area and forces redrawing.